# GUI problems: black boxes and bottom menu bar

Tags: 12.04, gui, menu-bar

After rebooting Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS i unexpectedly saw menu bar not in the top (as always) but in the bottom. 'Hidden' menu bar in the top are still working, e.g. i can restart operating system. See screen:
[image]

Also keeping mouse on the side bar makes it black (i can't make a screenshot because when i click PrtSc button all screen becomes black).
Any suggestions?

PS: before this i installed kvm packages, don't know if it can help (i haven't been rebooting for a long time so i'm not absolutely sure that it's a reason).

Before posting question i tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

But it didn't help.

**UPDATe**: Issue was resolved. Thanks to @bain, `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` works perfect!

Comment: What was the command you used to install the kvm packages you mention?

Comment: Parto, I used this sudo apt-get install kvm libvirt-bin python-virtinst bridge-utils and this: sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils

Comment: Does the error still occur if you create a new user account and log in to that?

Comment: @bain, yes,  i just tried it.

Comment: When you installed kvm did any other packages get upgraded? Like xorg, or the Linux kernel? You can check the logs in `/var/log/apt`. If so, you can either try to downgrade those packages, or do a full `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade to 12.04.4 and hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: @bain, Brilliant! It works like a charm! Thank you! Upgrading to 12.04.4 fixed the issue!

Comment: @bain Hey, want to add an answer since it worked? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed kvm some other packages probably got upgraded (probably xorg or the kernel) and those packages are buggy, resulting in your graphics problem. You are still running 12.04.2, try upgrading to the latest release (12.04.4) by doing `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`